# Text property for text box is not displaying its value

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects that I'm adding to.

```
private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
```

I have a button on my form application to create a new employee object and add it to the list. Prior to clicking it, it displays "Add Hourly Employee". After clicking it, it changes to "Save Hourly Employee". I'm just using a boolean to determine what text to display.

```
private void addHrlyEmpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resetBtn.Enabled = true;
        cancelBtn.Enabled = true;

        if (!addHourly)
        {
            resetBtn.Enabled = true;
            cancelBtn.Enabled = true;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Text = (employees.Count + 1).ToString();
            textBox7.Enabled = false;
            addHrlyEmpBtn.Text = "Save Hourly Employee";
        }
        else if (addHourly)
        {
            //Grab values, create new object, and add to list.
            //Set addHourly to false;
        }
        //Other stuff
    }
```

I'm trying to display `employees.Count + 1` to `textBox4`, but for some reason it isn't working. No text is being displayed at all. Idealy, I'd like to have the text box disabled but still display the value. And I only want it to display when `!addHourly`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: By "isn't working", do you mean there's no text entered at all, or the wrong value is displayed?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you set textBox4.Text = "test", do you see the string?

Comment: is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: Have you checked if the item is added to the list employees. Breakpoint should help you

Comment: @Matt No, there is no text if I set textBox4.Text = "test"

Comment: @arjunshetty2020 By the time I get to this point, there are already 4 objects in the list. If I set a breakpoint, employees.Count == 4.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but try to set the text before you set `textBox4.Enabled = false`

Comment: @AlexGelman Yeah, I've tried that too. Nothing...

Comment: Can you make textBox4 a label instead and try that?  Maybe some property on the textbox is preventing it?

Comment: Also, make sure that the PasswordChar property of the textbox has nothing in it.  Just because it's blank doesn't mean that a spacebar hasn't been used in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if addHrlyEmpBtn_Click is being called at all.

if it isn't try associating the Click event with addHrlyEmpBtn_Click method from the designer

or add `addHrlyEmpBtn.Click += addHrlyEmpBtn_Click;` in the constructor

Comment: It is. I can step through the entire method just fine.

Comment: Then probably you're setting it somewhere else which overwrites "Save Hourly Employee" i.e. if you're entirely sure that it went through the if branch

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but I can't figure out where. Let me ask you this. If I step through that if branch, once it gets to TextBox4.Text = "test"; should it immediately show in the text box?

Comment: Yes ... after it's stopped debugging though. however I'd suggest to search for other "addHrlyEmpBtn.Text = " instances and put a breakpoint at each instance of "addHrlyEmpBtn.Text =" you find. Then see if any of the bp gets hit AFTER it hits the one you've placed at the code you've posted

Comment: I figured it out. There was a rogue line that was calling Clear() on that text box.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong in principal with the code you wrote.

I would strongly suggest giving meaningful names to all of your variables.  Names like *textBox4* are likely to cause confusion for yourself and future maintainers of the code.

If the value is not changing as you expect, you are most likely not entering that *if* branch.

Set a breakpoint at

```
if (!addHourly)
```

See if *addHourly* has the value you expect.

Comment: I've done that and it is getting the value I expect. Also, I agree with you. Something meaningful would be ideal. However, this code was inherited from someone else and I don't feel like making the changes.